# Dojo equivalent of jQuery $('html')

Tags: jquery, html, dom, dojo

There is a shorthand way of selecting the body of the document in Dojo:
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/body.html

But how do I select the top of the DOM tree, which is the HTML element itself? In jQuery this can be done with $('html'), I am looking for an equivalent of that method in Dojo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require(["dojo/query"], function(query){
  var html = query("html")[0];
});
```